# how to add reove active class on up and down arrow keys in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am tying to implement dropdown
[image]

here is the image

now i want to add active class to option 1 and on keypress event like up and down i want to move between options

here is what i have tried

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item");
    console.log(btns[3]);
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[0].classList.add("active");
      btns[i].addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.key === 38 || e.key === 40) {
          var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
          current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active", "");
          this.className += "active";
        }
      });
    }

  });
```

here is how i am rendering dropdown list

```
  const options = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"];

 {open && (
            <ul className="list" id="lists">
              {options.map((option, i) => (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelected(option);
                    setOpen(false);
                  }}
                  className="list-item"
                >
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
```

please help me i am stuck here from 2 days.
i can add active class to first option but it is not switching on up and down key press

thanks in advance